# Find $\int_{1/e}^{\tan x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}+\int_{1/e}^{\cot x}\frac{dt}{t(1+t^2)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{1/e}^{\tan x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}+\int_{1/e}^{\cot x}\frac{dt}{t(1+t^2)}$$

Using Leibniz rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b{t}}f(x)dx=f(b(t))\frac{d}{dt}b(t)-f(a(t))\frac{d}{dt}a(t)
$$
Using that
$$
I=I_1+I_2=\int_{1/e}^{\tan x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}+\int_{1/e}^{\cot x}\frac{dt}{t(1+t^2)}
$$
$$
I^{'}_1(x)=\frac{\sec^2x}{1+\tan^2x}=1\implies I_1(x)=x+C_1\\
I_1(0)=C_1=\Big[\tan^{-1}x\Big]_{1/e}^0=-\tan^{-1}(1/e)\implies \boxed{I_1(x)=x-\tan^{-1}(1/e)}
$$
$$
I^{'}_2(x)=\frac{-\csc^2x}{\cot x(1+\cot^2x)}=-\tan x\implies I_2(x)=-\log|\sec x|+C_2=\log|\cos x|+C\\
I_2(\pi/4)=-\log\sqrt{2}+C_2=-\frac{1}{2}\log 2+C_2=\int_{1/e}^{1}\Big[\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{1+t^2}\Big]dt=\Big[\log t-\frac{1}{2}\log|1+t^2|\Big]_{1/e}^1\\
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2+C_2=-\frac{1}{2}\log 2+1-\frac{1}{2}\log|1+\frac{1}{e^2}|\\
C_2=1-\frac{1}{2}\log|1+\frac{1}{e^2}|
$$
If $1$ is the solution taking the derivating of $I(t)$ is supposed to give zero right, so what is going wrong here ?

**Note:** The solution given in my reference is $1$

Comment: From where did you get this problem? And did you copy it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluation of $\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{\tan x}\frac{t}{1+t^2}dt+\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{\cot x}\frac{1}{t(1+t^2)}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850568/evaluation-of-int-frac1e-tan-x-fract1t2dt-int-frac1e). If the result is $1$ then the first integral should be $\frac{t}{1+t^2}$ and you can find more in that link.

Comment: If the answer is supposed to be $1$, then you may have a typo in the problem. See the link in the Zacky's comment

Comment: @Zacky I hate this kinda typo in books, a simple letter can make the whole thing different.

Answer (score 1):

In order that both expressions are defined over an interval, we have to assume $0<x<\pi/2$.

Note that
$$
\int_{1/e}^{\tan x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt=\Bigl[\arctan t\Bigr]_{1/e}^{\tan x}=x-\arctan\frac{1}{e}
$$
For the second integral, the partial fraction decomposition is
$$
\frac{1}{t(1+t^2)}=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{1+t^2}
$$
so we have
$$
\int_{1/e}^{\cot x}\frac{1}{t(1+t^2)}\,dt=\Bigl[\log t-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+t^2)\Bigr]_{1/e}^{\cot x}
$$
The expression with $t=\cot x$ is
$$
\log\cot x-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+\cot^2x)=\log\cos x-\log\sin x+\log\sin x=\log\cos x
$$
For $t=1/e$ we get
$$
-1-\frac{1}{2}\log(e^2+1)+1=-\log\sqrt{e^2+1}
$$
Thus the final answer is
$$
x-\arctan\frac{1}{e}+\log\cos x+\log\sqrt{e^2+1}
$$

---

If the problem is
$$
\int_{1/e}^{\tan x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt+\int_{1/e}^{\cot x}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt
$$
then the second integral is
$$
\arctan\cot x-\arctan\frac{1}{e}=\frac{\pi}{2}-x-\arctan\frac{1}{e}
$$
and the whole expression is
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arctan\frac{1}{e}
$$